# Can't access SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I'm working on a project and now I had to switch account on the computer from local to a account on a domain and thus the windows authentication changed. So I made a new login and it works on the account that is on the domain, but when I change the connection string from

```
Data Source=productie3;
```

to

```
Data Source='MEVO/productie3';
//tried with either \ or /
//direct connection (using SQL Server Management Studio) to the database using the 
//windows authentication works fine
```

I tried it without the single quotes as well,
But it still doesn't work.

I've used this to allow remove access

```
USE [DB name];
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 0 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

But it still won't allow it to connect, if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong please tell me. I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` for the database.

Comment: With SQL server the `DataSource` is the *server*, a backslash is used to select a specific instance. Use the `Database` setting to select a specific database.

Comment: I'm not trying to get a specific database from the server since that didn't change. All that changed is that I am now working from a domain thus I have to edit the source of the connection. Perhaps I made a bit of a mistake in the question on that part.

Comment: One does not specify the domain when specifying machine names (unlike user names).

Comment: I don't quite get why but I changed it to the computer name that it is on and it works like you said (in the above comment) but before it was set as `productie3` and the pc name is `PRODUCTIE03`, Could it be that it worked before because it was installed from that account?

Comment: @maam27 but did you try to leave as it was before?. If your machine named `productie3` is on your LAN you don't need to change the connection string if you use Windows Authentication. If you want to reach it from an outside the lan you need a lot more of configuration. (IP or public URL, firewall at the router level etc....)

Comment: I didn't change anything the first time i tried to run it after setting it to a diffrent pc, because i tried to see if the application would still run (diffrent visual studio, some errors opening the file, etc) but it wouldn't even open because of the database error. After that i tried to change it. But it's working again now

Comment: If you have solved your question then please either post the answer that solved your question or vote to close your question as _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error..."_ It is not accepted to mark your question as "solved" in the title

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with a backslash. You are putting in a forward slash.

```
Data Source='MEVO\productie3';
```

Comment: I did have that before I tried the current, still didn't work. Forgot to note that

Comment: What is the Exception you get?

Comment: It takes a while to attempt to connect and then gives me this: An unhandled exception of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExeption` occurred in System.Data.dll. additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SWL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Since you have mentioned that Windows Authentication works, have you tried it with Integrated Authentication or are you using User Id?

Comment: the login authentication is set to `Windows authentication` and not the `SQL Server Authentication`.

Comment: I suppose you could say I tried to connect to the wrong area, since it used to connect to the same name as the user account, and now it went to a account on a network domain I figured I had to change the Data Source for the windows authentication. but it seems that i just had to change it from user account to the pc name.